# Python: using command-line option to access a tuple

Tags: python, tuples, command-line-arguments

I want to pass a short product code when running my script:
`./myscript.py --productcode r|u|c`
Then use the short product code to look up data stored in a tuple in the python code:

```
# create tuples for each product
r=("Redhat","7.2")
u=("Ubuntu","7.5")
c=("Centos","8.1") 

# parse the command line
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--productcode", help="Short code for product")
options=parser.parse_args()
# get the product code
product_code=options.productcode

# Access elements in the relevant tuple
product_name=product_code[0]
product_version=product_code[1]
```

Comment: Store the tuples in a dict, then use `product_code` as the key - e.g. `products[product_code]`

Comment: I might need a list of dictionaries:`[{'product_code':'c', 'product_name':'CentOS','product_version':'7.8'},
 {'product_code':'r', 'product_name':'Redhat','product_version':'7.6'},
 {'product_code':'u', 'product_name':'Ubuntu','product_version':'8.1'}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was already mentioned in the comment,
you can store tuples in a dictionary with the matching keys.

```
import argparse

mapping = {
    'r': ("Redhat", "7.2"),
    'u': ("Ubuntu", "7.5"),
    'c': ("Centos", "8.1"),
}

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--productcode", help="Short code for product")
options = parser.parse_args()

product = mapping[options.productcode]
print(product[0])
print(product[1])
```

In this case:

```
$ python script.py --productcode c
Centos
8.1
```

Alternatively, you can create the mapping dynamically (here I used namedtuple instead of a regular tuple).

```
import argparse
import sys
from collections import namedtuple

Product = namedtuple('Product', ['name', 'version', 'code'])
redhat = Product("Redhat", "7.2", 'r')
ubuntu = Product("Ubuntu", "7.5", 'u')
centos = Product("Centos", "8.1", 'c')

mapping = {
    item.code: item
    for item in locals().values()
    if isinstance(item, Product)
}

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--productcode", help="Short code for product")
options = parser.parse_args()

product = mapping[options.productcode]
print(product.name)
print(product.version)
```